# Changing translatex and translatey for child items in Materializecss Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, materialize

I am creating a Carousel in materializecss, I am looking to change the `translateX` and `translateY` property CSS to make the carousel look like the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working?

Comment: I have used the basic code from https://materializecss.com/carousel.html to use it need to know how to specify the JS to target the first child and change its position using css class transform: translateX() translateY()